# Creating a Run Configuration for Maven Project in Intelij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a simple standard `Maven` project that I have created using `Intelij`.

**Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.rs.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Main class:**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello all!");
    }
}
```

Currently I run this project by first:

```
mvn clean install
```

then navigate to target dir and run:

```
java -jar MavenExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How can I create a run configuration in `intelij` to run this project without needing to manually run the jar command?

Comment: Have you tried to run the Main class from your IDE? There is usually a green icon on the main line...which shows that you can execute it directly from there...BTW: `mvn clean install` is not needed only `mvn clean package`...

Comment: Thanks, is right clicking on the main the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which we can run our Java application. The commonly used ones are either from the command line or from the IDE itself.

**From command line**

1. `java -jar` command.

   Example:  `java -jar jar-name.jar`
2. `java -cp` command.

   Example: `java -cp jar-name.jar com.package.ClassName`

where `com.package.ClassName` is the class that contains the main method to run the program. cp in the above command stands for the classpath.

**From IDE**

Simply do the right-click in the class and you will be able to find the option to run your code. Just click on that option. Check this image for detail.

[image: Run main method]